# Notify users when an edit is rejected

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[Been seeing way too many "minimal" edits](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10757/been-seeing-way-too-many-minimal-edits?noredirect=1#comment32998_10757)

> @Schism - perhaps that's something that needs to be fixed? A
> notification that "Your edit was rejected, please view the reasons why
> and try and do better next time" would be good –  [Robotnik](https://stackexchange.com/users/919989/robotnik)

Would be extremely beneficial to let editors know what they are doing wrong if their edit is rejected, and would really help improve the quality of edits on the site.